# How to crop a cvPixelBuffer to the bounds of a CGRect?

Tags: ios, swift, core-video

I have a `CVPixelBuffer` of depth data obtained from an `AVCapturePhoto` object. I also have a CGRect that represents the bounds of a face in the photo. I want to crop the depth data to only have the data for the face left. How could I achieve this?

Comment: Hi @ymulki, did you find a solution for this?